# Transfer data from a web form to a user web control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I transfer data from a web form to a user web control ? does the diffrence in the programming language affect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the terminology of "user control" in the traditional ASP.NET WebForms sense, you can expose a property on the user control of any data type you like and set the value of that property on the web form containing the control.

Or the user control could get its data from the same place the parent form does.  Or you could persist the data from the parent form somewhere (session state, application state, a database, a file, whatever's appropriate for the setup) and access it from the user control.

If you can give an example of specifically what you're trying to do then it would be a little easier to help you architect an effective solution.